# Is mine process still a daemon?

Tags: c, linux

I'm relatively new to programming and my English might be little rusty so please be gentle :).

I'm trying to create a group of daemons that will belong to same group without group leader. I think I did it but I'm not sure if my method still meets the requirements (if my process is still a daemon)

This part is in 0.c

```
pid_t pid=fork();
if (pid==0)
{
    execl ("./1", "1", str, (char *)0);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    sleep(1);
}
```

This part of code is in 1.c

```
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
if (pid > 0)
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
gid = setsid();
if (gid < 0)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
gid = setsid();
if (gid < 0)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
pid_t pid=fork();
    if (pid==0)
    {
        execl ("./2", "2", str, str1, (char *)0);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

and this in 2

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
if (pid > 0)
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
umask(0);
chdir("./");
close(STDIN_FILENO);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);
```

Now let's say I have *n* processes 2 are they all daemons?

EDIT: I see now that those probably aren't daemons. Can someone explain to me then how to make daemons that will meet my requirements?

Comment: @ryyker: He definitely has multiple processes, from calling `fork()`

Comment: @BenVoigt - yes, thanks.  Differing semantics between windows and Linux.

Comment: @ryyker: Well, on Linux `fork` is a syscall and `spawn` is `fork+exec`, while on Windows `spawn` maps to a syscall and `fork` is not even possible (although cygwin emulates it in a way that usually works)... in neither case does it create a new thread in the same process.  ISTR `vfork` can be used for thread creation.

Comment: @BenVoigt - When I create a secondary thread in Windows (I use CVI, which is a C compiler packaged with extension for instrumentation) that thread does not spawn a new process.  It lives within the same process as the primary thread.  Just to be clear, I am speaking of the process visible in Task Manager.  Are we speaking of the same process?

Comment: @ryyker: Oh, there definitely exists a way to create multiple threads inside a process (Windows: `CreateThread`, Linux: `pthread_create`).  And there are also libraries and even language extensions that will automatically create threads for you (C++ std::future, OpenMP, etc).  But nothing in the question is dealing in threads, only entire new processes.

Comment: Read carefully [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) and consider using it...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Normally daemons need to disassociate from their controlling terminal, or at least ignore `SIGHUP`, and you don't appear to be doing this.</strike>

So no, I do not think your code is achieving daemon status.

After further investigation, I found that `setsid()` disassociates the controlling terminal, among other actions.  So please disregard this.

Comment: doesn't the first part disassociate from controlling terminal?

Comment: @Thomas - When it runs, can you test it's existence by using the criteria _[here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159967)_?

Answer (score 0):

Anything with the PPID of 1 is, for the most part, likely a daemon. 
You can check the likelihood that your process is a daemon then by executing: (command line)

```
$ ps -xj
```

There is much more *[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159967)* discussing ways to test for daemon.

And *[here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/c-daemon-process/)* discussing creating a daemon in general. (using C)